# Bash more direct way of loading values into files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this code:

```
echo 'deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx' >> /tmp/nginx.list
echo 'deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx' >> /tmp/nginx.list
cp /tmp/nginx.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
rm /tmp/nginx.list
```

This seems quite long winded. Is there a more direct approach to putting this information in a file without having to use a tmp file?

Comment: Sorry I should I specified, this is in an automated deployment script

Comment: Use a "here" document maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to make use of a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list << EOF
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to a heredoc is to use a command group to aggregate the standard output of a series of commands under one output redirection. (This is useful if you have additional logic to generate the output, other than a simple sequence of `echo` statements.)

```
{
  echo 'deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx'
  echo 'deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx'
} > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
```